# Access UITableView section header label

Tags: ios, uitableview, sectionheader

is there a way to customize the section header label without drawing my own view first?

I just want to change the alignment of the label.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 6, you could use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. This has a property `textLabel`, which gives you access to the label that's being drawn. I haven't worked with it a whole lot, but you may have to configure a few other things before it looks 100% like a table header label.

Comment: So there is no easy way to do it? That is a huge bummer!

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've wanted this for a long time, too. Please file an enhancement request so that hopefully it gets enough attention. Now would be a better time than any.

Comment: yeah I know haha. I mean they are fixing a couple things lately. So thats something I guess.